# OCaml - how to catch exception

Tags: exception, ocaml

I have a question.

Sometimes Map.find return exception Not_Found. How to catch it and continue program ?
I ask for example :D

Answer (score 3):

Use the `try / with` expression

```
try expr with Not_Found -> defaultValue
```

This site has a nice tutorial on OCaml Exceptions

> http://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/ocaml-class/exceptions.html